# Create an ISO 8601 Duration in Javascript/Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iso8601

How would I create a duration in JavaScript then format this as an ISO 8601 duration, for example 2 mins 30 seconds would be "PT2M30S".

Could this be done with an $interval? Or can this be achieved with Date().getTime()?

I have an interaction that I need to track time spent on, so would I get the date at the start or the interaction and then again at the end, subtract from each other then format as ISO 8601? Struggling to find correct syntax or a useful lib.

Comment: If you have date object then you can simply use [`Date.prototype.toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

Comment: @Satpal—the OP wants a duration, not a date and time.

Comment: If your times are short (say less than a month) then you can simply subtract one date from the other to get the difference in milliseconds, then convert to an interval. The only issue is daylight saving boundaries. Durations of months and years require a bit more work as they aren't a consistent length.

Answer (score 1):

Wrapped up a small package to help with this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/tinyduration

Usage example:

```js
import { parse, serialize } from 'tinyduration';
 
// Basic parsing
const durationObj = parse('P1Y2M3DT4H5M6S');
assert(durationObj, {
    years: 1,
    months: 2,
    days: 3,
    hours: 4,
    minutes: 5,
    seconds: 6
});
 
// Serialization
assert(serialize(durationObj), 'P1Y2M3DT4H5M6S');
```

You can install it using `npm install --save tinyduration` or `yarn add tinyduration`

Answer (score 0):

#### For Angular (2+)

You can use my [ngx-duration-picker](https://github.com/FrancescoBorzi/ngx-duration-picker) which allows the user to select a duration and automatically converts it to the ISO 8601 format.

A live demo is available [here](https://francescoborzi.github.io/ngx-duration-picker/index.html).

Answer (score -1):

[Moment](http://momentjs.com/) is a very popular date manipulation library for JavaScript that's capable of formatting duration in ISO8601. Here's an example of how to first calculate a diff between two dates, and then generate a duration string from that diff.

```js
var first = moment("2015-10-01"),
  second = moment("2015-10-02");

console.log(moment.duration(second.diff(first), "ms").toISOString());
// "PT24H"
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.26.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Have a look at the [documentation for duration formatting](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/) for more details.

Comment: `moment.diff()` returns ms, which means it would not be possible to represent the period (party) in days anymore, as not every day has the same length (DST etc).