# calculating time difference in iso time format in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, datetime

I have two date string in ISO format. I am calculating the minutes difference between them using moment js.

```
var currenttime  =  new Date().toISOString();
var expiretime  = '2020-06-05T12:18:33.000Z';


let minutes = moment(expiretime, 'YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss. SSS[Z]').diff(moment(currenttime, 'YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss. SSS[Z]'), 'minutes');


console.log(minutes)
```

Now i have two questions

1. Is this is the best way to calculate the minutes difference ?
2. When i run `new Date().toISOString()` the value before `z` is the supposed to be the timezone but on every restart it changes ?

Please let me know what is the issue ?

Comment: If you really want the "*time difference in ISO time format*", see [Create an ISO 8601 Duration in Javascript/Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33822094/257182).

Comment: Re: "*the value before z is the supposed to be the timezone but on every restart it changes*", note that *toISOString* is always UTC, the bit before the Z is actually the time and Z is the timezone offset, it represents +00:00 or UTC. If you want the offset as ±HHMM, use format and ZZ: `moment().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZZ')` for local offset, or `moment().utc().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZZ')` for UTC.

Answer (score 10):

I don't think you have to include moment for this purpose only, this can be done in ordinary Javascript.
To calculate time difference just subtract the two timestamps which will give the difference in milliseconds. Then divide by `60*1000` which will give the time difference in minutes.

```
let currentTime = new Date();
let expireTime = new Date('2020-06-05T12:18:33.000Z');

let minutes = (expireTime - currentTime) / (1000 * 60);

console.log(minutes);
```

Comment: Can u tell me why  z value changes ? also does moment is wrong?

Comment: the "z" value is actually milliseconds, not time zone. Z means zulu, so dates in this representation are always in UTC. If you want to specify time zone, you'd write +04:30 after it (or whatever your time offset is).

Comment: @Dennis— AIUI, "Z" is the identifier for GMT or UTC in the standard [military timezone identifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_military_time_zones) used by a variety of countries such as US, UK, Aus, etc. The name "Zulu" comes from the phonetic alphabet, where "Z" is called "Zulu".  So rather than Z standing for Zulu, it's actually the other way around: Zulu stands for Z. :-) PS Military timezones only have hourly increments so don't cover some offsets or daylight saving, so Z is the only one that's in common civilian use. It's also used by ISO 8601.

Comment: @RobG I'm aware of that, but OP asked a different question. They asked why the "z value changes", misunderstanding that the value before z is actually *milliseconds*, whereas a timezone value would come after milliseconds, or be represented by Z (Zulu time, equivalent to UTC).

Answer (score 2):

For your first question, what you can do is simply subtract the two dates (date objects and not strings) ,

Newer date - Older date ( this will give the result in milliseconds)

or use Math.abs() function to calculate milliseconds -

```
var msec = Math.abs( currenttime - expiretime );
```

and convert this to minutes using -

```
var min = Math.floor((msec/1000)/60);
```

2)
Z in the datetime string stands for Zulu, it indicates that the time is in UTC format.
You can simply subtract two date objects.

```
var currenttime = new Date();
var currenttime_UTC = currenttime.getUTCDate();
var expiretime = new Date('2020-06-05T12:18:33.000Z');

var msec = Math.abs( currenttime_UTC - expiretime );
var min = Math.floor((msec/1000)/60);
```

Comment: No, moment will work too, but if you are using it just for this purpose, then the code in the above 2 comments will suffice.